# Getting the count of the second index in a muti-dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I want to get the count for the second index in an array, and have searched for quite a while, but still haven't found an answer, and still have no idea how. Please take a look:

```
$array[0][0] = 1;
$array[0][1] = 2;
$array[0][2] = 3;

$arrayCount = count($array);
echo $arrayCount;
```

output would be:

```
1
```

However, I actually want the count of the second index. If I am able to get it, the output would be:

```
3
```

Is there any way to get the count of the second index? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: try $arrayCount = count($array[0]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to count `$array` which is one.

If you are looking for counting array index, use

```
$arrayCount = count($array[0]);
```

Hope it helps.